# Split SQL rows between 4 flags

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I divide every 4 rows of data between different users.

i.e.

```
Number

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Then run a query so that I get the following format:

```
Number | User 
1      | joe
2      | jim
3      | gill
4      | jack
5      | joe
6      | jim
7      | gill
8      | jack
```

etc.

UPDATE

My Code ended up being (T-SQL / SQL 2008)

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) % 4 = 1 THEN 'joe'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) % 4 = 2 THEN 'jim'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) % 4 = 3 THEN 'gill'
    WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) % 4 = 0 THEN 'jack'
END
```

Comment: You could use the other CASE syntax in this situation: `CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) % 4 WHEN 1 THEN 'joe' WHEN 2 THEN 'jim' WHEN 3 THEN 'gill' WHEN 0 THEN 'jack' END` would be much shorter with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When number has some gaps:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number), 4) = 1 THEN 'joe'
        WHEN MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number), 4) = 2 THEN 'jim'
        WHEN MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number), 4) = 3 THEN 'gill'
        WHEN MOD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number), 4) = 0 THEN 'jack'
    END
FROM t
```

Comment: Mod is not a recognized built in function allegedly :/ Using SQL Server 2008 by the way. Cheers for the reply

Answer (score 6):

Just use the modulus operator in a `case` statement:

```
select number,
       (case when mod(number, 4) = 1 then 'joe'
             when mod(number, 4) = 2 then 'jim'
             when mod(number, 4) = 3 then 'gill'
             when mod(number, 4) = 0 then 'jack'
        end)
from t;
```

Comment: Mod is not a recognized built in function allegedly :/ Using SQL Server 2008 by the way. Cheers for the reply.